# HandbrakeCLI convert audio only

Tags: audio, video-conversion

My TV reads video files only with AAC or MP3 audio tracks.

I am trying to use HandBrakeCLI.exe to convert audio tracks only preserving video quality, but it takes as mush time as converting the whole video.
My command is:

```
HandBrakeCLI -i gp.avi -o mov.mp4 --aencoder="mp3"
```

Should I use another tool, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think HandbrakeCLI allows to copy the video stream. [The documentation](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide) only mentions an option to copy audio. So your command would re-encode the video and audio at the same time, which explains why it takes so long to complete.

You could of course use another tool. With [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), changing the audio to MP3 or AAC, while keeping the video stream intact, is very simple:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 -c:v copy output.avi
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -c:v copy output.mp4
```

But that assumes your original doesn't already have MP3 or AAC audio, which I think is very unlikely. (What else would it be other than raw PCM audio?) Either way, those commands will force MP3 or AAC.

For setting the quality or choosing other encoders, read the [MP3 guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3) and the [AAC guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC).

Comment: Wow, that works fast. I knew about ffmpeg, I just didn't know there were user-friendly builds for Windows